# Django uploaded images come up too big on the pages

Tags: django, image, upload, size

I am a django learner, I went through what's in the "Python crash course" book and currently making really simple website just to memorise what's after what and get more familiar with the basics.

Can someone explain to me why the images I upload come up enormously big on the pages or how to fix that, please? I couldn't really find anything like that so far.

Don't pay attention to the rubbish writings on there. It's just about a german shepherd. Complicated relationship...

[image: That's how images show on the web pages],

[image: Actual image] and

[image: Actual image].

Comment: You should google setting image resolution in HTML and/or Django.

Comment: Yeah,  thanks for that. I was just trying to find out why it was doing it. I've installed pillow as well and I thought that and the ImageField()  in Django would take care of all the work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django ImageField provides width and height arguments that you can use to automaticaly resize uploaded images. More documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField).

However if you have a rendering issue, that might be related to your HTML/CSS. Fix the height with CSS/HTML attributes.

Comment: Oh yeah  thanks for that, I should've seen that about the arguments, really.  It will probably do the trick. Anyway, I thought the same thing, just play with it when I get to the styling... Thanks for the answer

Comment: Learner mistake, no problem. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue.